# uploading using Mashape to upload to imgur always says image corrupted or not format not supported

Tags: php, base64, imgur, mashape

I'm using `MashApe` `API` to upload images to `Imgur` using `PHP` as follows:

```
$valid_file_extensions = array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png");

        $file_extension = strrchr($_FILES["file"]["name"], ".");

        if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_file_extensions)) {
            if (@getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) !== false) {

                $filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
                $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

                $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com/3/image",
                    array(
                        "X-Mashape-Key" => "key",
                        "Authorization" => "Client-ID ID",
                        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "image" => base64_encode($data)
                    )
                );

                var_dump(base64_encode($data));
                $result = json_decode($response->raw_body);

                if ($result->success) {
                    var_dump($result);
                } else {
                    $Pointer->Bootstrap()->Alert($result->data->error, "danger");
                }

            }
        }
```

but it always give me the following error: `Image is corrupted or format is not supported.`

Answer (score -2):

If you downloaded a webm and changed the file type to gif when you saved it, the conversion is too corrupt for imgur. Try [Cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/webm-to-gif) until one of us figures out how to do it offline.

I recommend ShareX for automatic uploads to imgur.